# Designing Butterworth Filter

Tags: filter, signal-processing, digital-filter

I want to design butterworth filter in matlab only based on order of the filter and the cutoff frequency in Hz.

the syntax is for returning the ABCD matrix of statespace is

```
[A,B,C,D] = butter(____)
```

I tried doing below for 2nd order and 30Hz cut off

```
[A, B, C, D] = butter(2,30)
```

But i get an error saying :

```
Error using butter (line 41)
The cutoff frequencies must be within the interval of
(0,1).
```

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: Who is giving you the error? M$ Office?

Comment: I thought it was understood that i was designing in matlab, sorry for confusion. I have edited the question

Comment: "[___] = butter(___,'s') designs a lowpass, highpass, bandpass, or bandstop analog Butterworth filter with cutoff angular frequency Wn." Directly taken from the help file, please learn how to use other resources other than an online community. IDK if your reading the help file before you post, if your not you should. Please also see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask please follow the recommendations before posting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because not much research was done before posting

Comment: Hello, Sorry for the confusion. I did check the help. But as you posted, Wn is cutoff angular frequncy, so i just converted my cut off frequency to rads/sec. Which was giving me an error. Turns out Wn was actually normalized cut off frequrency as shown below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Matlab to calculate the filter, judging from the syntax and function parameters.

butter calculates a normalized low pass filter response. If you are in the z domain, the actual cut-off frequency depends on your nyquist frequency (half your sampling frequency).
If you sample with say 2MSPS, you have a Nyquist frequency of 1MHz and butter with Wn=0.5 would have a cut-off frequency of 500kHz.
See also [this discussion](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/145198) on matlab central.

You should read "doc butter" to get started and might also want to read a textbook on filter design. 
From the documentation:

```
[b,a] = butter(n,Wn) designs an order n lowpass digital Butterworth filter with normalized cutoff frequency Wn. It returns the filter coefficients in length n+1 row vectors b and a, with coefficients in descending powers of z.
```

Comment: Hey! thanks your your detailed answer. i am little behind on some basics. but i want in state space representation. Say i want to desgin a butterworth filter for Cut off frequency of 35Hz. how would i do it '[A,B,C,D] = butter(2, __)'

Comment: As I said, you need to know your sampling rate if you want to relate the normalized frequency Wn to the actual frequency. If you clock your system faster, the cut off frequency will also move up. It doesn't matter whether you design in state space or not. If you want to calculate a continuous filter, you should use the parameter butter( ___, 's'). Again, this works for statespace as well.

Comment: My Ts = 0.025. I am not sure of the unit you posted.

Comment: The Unit is Megasamples per second. Your Ts would give you 1/Ts = 40 Samples per second (40 SPS). This means that you cannot achieve 30Hz cutoff, because your Nyquist frequency is already at 20Hz. You need a lower Ts to make it work.

Comment: If Ts is sampling period, invert it to get the sampling frequency, and half that to get the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: Thank You!. I just reduced my Ts to 0.0027, so my Fs = 370.37. So my Nyquist frequency = 185.185.

Comment: And how do i find Wn, I am not sure what Wn is in this syntax?

Comment: Wn is your normalized Nyquist frequency, meaning Wn = 1 is the nyquist frequency, Wn = 0.5 is 0.5*f_Nyquist. To calculate f_Nyquist, see the comment of @BrianDrummond

Comment: Ah i get it now! But is there a way that i design the filter based on the order and the cutoff frequency?

Comment: There are [tools available](http://de.mathworks.com/help/dsp/gs/design-a-filter-using-filterbuilder.html)  to help you with that. I suggest you ask a new question where you detail your requirements. Before that, it might be good to catch up on some basics. If the answer helped you, you might want to accept it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just looked around some material, can you please check if this is a correct approach. My Fs = 370, My Fc = 30Hz. so the syntax is [A,B,C,D] = butter(2, 30/(370/2)).

Comment: Seems correct to me. You can check it by building a system ( sys=ss(A,B,C,D) ) and checking bode(sys)